# How to use line with width of three.js with morphTargets to animate one line moving to another

Tags: animation, three.js

[question reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71611810/animate-every-point-of-a-line-to-another-line-with-three-js/71615111#71615111)
I want to implement an animation.

The animation should be a line move to another line. There will be some deformation in the process of the line moving

There is a correspondence between the points of the two lines.

I can use the basic line of three.js to animate one line moving to another.

```
<script type="module">
    import * as THREE from '../../build/three.module.js'
    import { OrbitControls } from '../jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js'

    function main() {
        var scene = new THREE.Scene()
        const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setAttribute('position',
            new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute([-2, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, -0.5, 0, 0, -2], 3))
        const geometry1 = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setAttribute('position',
            new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute([5, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 5], 3))
        geometry.morphAttributes.position = [
            geometry1.attributes.position,
        ]
        var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
            color: 0x0000ff,
        }) 
        var mesh = new THREE.Line(geometry, material)
        mesh.morphTargetInfluences[0] = 0
        scene.add(mesh) 
        /**
         * 
         */
        var width = window.innerWidth 
        var height = window.innerHeight 
        var k = width / height
        var s = 10 
        
        var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
            -s * k,
            s * k,
            s,
            -s,
            -1500,
            1500
        )
        camera.position.set(10, 10, 10) 
        camera.lookAt(10, 0, 0) 
        /**
         * 
         */
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
        // window.renderer = renderer;
        renderer.setSize(width, height)
        renderer.setClearColor(0xb9d3ff, 1) 
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement) 

        // renderer.render(scene, camera);
        new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement) 

        var clock = new THREE.Clock()
        const axes = new THREE.AxesHelper(10)
        scene.add(axes)

        let flag = false
        let index = 0

        function render() {
            renderer.render(scene, camera) 
            requestAnimationFrame(render)
            if (index <0) {
                flag = true
            } else if (index > 1) {
                flag = false
            }
            if (flag) {
                index += 0.01
            } else {
                index -= 0.01
            }
            mesh.morphTargetInfluences[0] = index
            console.log(flag, index)
        }

        render()
    }

    main()

</script>
```

Now I want to use the LineGeometry of three.js because this line has a width property. How to use the morphtargets with LineGeometry?

If the LineGeometry can't do it,any other bufferGeometry to replace LineGeometry?

Three.js 136.

```
<script type="module">
    import * as THREE from '../../build/three.module.js'
    import { OrbitControls } from '../jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js'
    import { Line2 } from '../jsm/lines/Line2.js'
    import { LineMaterial } from '../jsm/lines/LineMaterial.js'
    import { LineGeometry } from '../jsm/lines/LineGeometry.js'

    function main() {
        var scene = new THREE.Scene()
        const geometry2 = new LineGeometry()
        geometry2.setPositions([-3, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, -0.5, 0, 0, -2])
        console.log(geometry2)

        const geometry1 = new LineGeometry()
        geometry1.setPositions([-3, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, -3])
        geometry2.morphAttributes.position = [geometry1.attributes.position]
        let matLine = new LineMaterial({
            color: '#ffdb2d',
            linewidth: 5, // in world units with size attenuation, pixels otherwise
        })
        let line = new Line2(geometry2, matLine)
        line.morphTargetInfluences[0] = 0
        scene.add(line)

        /**
         */
        var width = window.innerWidth
        var height = window.innerHeight
        var k = width / height
        var s = 5

        var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
            -s * k,
            s * k,
            s,
            -s,
            -1500,
            1500
        )
        camera.position.set(5, 5, 5)
        camera.lookAt(5, 0, 0)
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
        // window.renderer = renderer;
        renderer.setSize(width, height)
        renderer.setClearColor(0xb9d3ff, 1)
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)
        // renderer.render(scene, camera);
        new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
        var clock = new THREE.Clock()
        const axes = new THREE.AxesHelper(10)
        scene.add(axes)

        let flag = false
        let index = 0

        function render() {
            renderer.render(scene, camera)
            requestAnimationFrame(render)
            if (index < 0) {
                flag = true
            } else if (index > 1) {
                flag = false
            }
            if (flag) {
                index += 0.01
            } else {
                index -= 0.01
            }
            line.morphTargetInfluences[0] = index
            matLine.resolution.set(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight) // resolution of the viewport
        }

        render()
    }

    main()

</script>
```

Comment: The wide line implementation of `three.js` does not support morph targets.

Comment: @Mugen87
Any other method to implement it? Like a cylinder mesh to replace LineGeometry.

Comment: Maybe using a [TubeGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/geometries/TubeGeometry) would be an option. You can generate it along a path and also use morph target animation since it's a simple mesh.

Answer (score 0):

Use TubeGeometry:

```
const curve = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3([new THREE.Vector3(-2, 0, 0), new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, 0, -0.5), new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -2)])
    var tubeGeometry = new THREE.TubeGeometry(curve, 100, 0.05, 50, false);
    const curve1 = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3([new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 5,), new THREE.Vector3( 1, 1, 1,), new THREE.Vector3(5, 0, 0,)])
    var tubeGeometry1 = new THREE.TubeGeometry(curve1, 100, 0.05, 50, false);
    tubeGeometry.morphAttributes.position = [
        tubeGeometry1.attributes.position,
    ]
    var tubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        side:THREE.DoubleSide,
        color:'#ffffff',
    });
    var tube = new THREE.Mesh(tubeGeometry, tubeMaterial);
    tube.morphTargetInfluences[0] = 0
    scene.add(tube)
```

In the render function:

```
tube.morphTargetInfluences[0] += 0.01
```